# how to design in bootstrap textbox and lable without space

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need some help for front end side. i have below picture i want to design form like below picture in bootstrap but in bootstrap how do this please help check my below html.

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">                                    
                                            <label>Flight No</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Departure Date</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">D/Time</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Arrival Date</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub-Agent Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-1">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>A/Time</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Arrival Sector</label>
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 30px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Terminal</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

i want like this
[image: i want like this]

my bootstrap
[image]

Comment: post your css also

Comment: use `inline-form`:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_inline&stacked=h

Comment: See here:https://jsfiddle.net/wdkhyrLb/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to Update with this CSS and HTML. It's Responsive so you can check properly. I hope this one help you.

```css
.form-group,
.form-group label,
.form-group input { float:left; display:inline; }
input{
  width:100px;
}
label{
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <form class="form-inline">
  
                                  
                                            <label>Flight No</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name" >                                        
                                 
                                    
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Departure Date</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
                                        </div>
                                   
                                  
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">D/Time</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
                                        </div>
                                 
                                   
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Arrival Date</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub-Agent Name">
                                        </div>
                                  
                                 
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>A/Time</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">
                                        </div>
                                  
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Arrival Sector</label>
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
                                            <input type="text" style="width: 30px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
                                        </div>
                                    
                                  
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Terminal</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
                                        </div>
                                  
                                 
                                    </form>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
   @media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-inline .form-group {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     vertical-align: middle;
     display: inline-flex;
    }
   }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="col-md-12 form-inline"> 
     <div class="col-md-2" style="display: inline-flex;">                                    
       <label>Flight No</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">                                        
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Departure Date</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">D/Time</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Arrival Date</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub-Agent Name">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>A/Time</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Arrival Sector</label>
       <input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
       <input type="text" style="width: 30px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Terminal</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
label {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    display: contents !important;
}
.form-control {
display: initial !important;
width: auto !important;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <label>Flight No</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Departure Date</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">D/Time</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Arrival Date</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Sub-Agent Name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>A/Time</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Agent Name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Arrival Sector</label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 20px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
    <input type="text" style="width: 30px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Voucher No">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Terminal</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Reference">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```